# FlashBuilder/AIR - Debugging production version of app

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have an App deployed for iOS which was built with FlashBuilder and Air. I have a user that has reported a bug that I am currently unable to reproduce. He is the only one reporting the issue. His device, iPod Touch, has the latest iOS software, 6. The issue causes the App to crash and lockup the iPod Touch to the point that he has to reboot the device.

I am trying to find out if there are any options out there to assist me with debugging his issue - remote debugging, logging, etc.?

Thanks, in advance, for any replies.

Comment: I don't think this question is concretely answerable so I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the appropriate place to ask it.  I'm not sure what to tell you other than buying an iPod Touch like his and installing the iOS 6 and performing the actions he performs in an attempt to replicate.

Comment: I actually bought one yesterday, by pure coincidence. With that said, I am unable to duplicate it at all. I was wanting to know if there was something like TestFlight that I might be able to use to aid in debugging, etc. Thanks for the reply

Comment: If you're in a corp environment; it may be possible to sit w/ the user and debug that way.  If this is someone who you never met, but bought your app through the app store you may be stuck.  You can ask him to take a video of his usage before the app crashes the device.

Comment: I might be stuck as it's thru the App store. He mentioned he was going to take a video of it. Hopefully I will be able to determine what's going on from it.